# Using Jquery for fadein/out. Fade out doesn't seem to be working correctly

Tags: jquery, fadeout, fadein

I've been working on a small page to create an interactive map of sorts.  The current site isn't representative of the final product, just getting the guts of the site and the coding set up.  I'm also very new to web coding in general, just fyi.

Here's my problem.

I'm trying to get a series of images to fade in and out using jquery based on clicking on a button.  The fade in / fade out seems to work perfect when progressing down the buttons, but when progressing the opposite direction, the fade out seems to be immediate, though the fade in works as it should.  I'd prefer the fade in / out to be uniform no matter which direction the button clicks are going, but can't seem to find the reason why the coding is working this way.

Here's the live link for all my source code:
http://users.humboldt.edu/eibenm/sheepallenge.html

I'm guessing the problem is in these sections:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Image1').fadeIn(1500);
})      

$(button1).click(function() {
    $('#sins img').fadeOut('slow');
    $('#Image1').fadeIn(1500);
}); 

$(button2).click(function() {
    $('#sins img').fadeOut('slow');
    $('#Image2').fadeIn(1500);
}); 

$(button3).click(function() {
    $('#sins img').fadeOut('slow');
    $('#Image3').fadeIn(1500);
}); 

$(button4).click(function() {
    $('#sins img').fadeOut('slow');
    $('#Image4').fadeIn(1500);
}); 

$(button5).click(function() {
    $('#sins img').fadeOut('slow');
    $('#Image5').fadeIn(1500);
}); 

$(button6).click(function() {
    $('#sins img').fadeOut('slow');
    $('#Image6').fadeIn(1500);
}); 

$(button7).click(function() {
    $('#sins img').fadeOut('slow');
    $('#Image7').fadeIn(1500);
});
```

Comment: Move all your Code into DOM Ready Handler..  Check if that helps

Comment: All in all, that seems like a really awful way of doing things?

Comment: You can shorten your code to a single event if you can add the data-attribute to your cosw

Answer (score 0):

You have lot of repetitive Inline styles , JQuery and HTML code.. It can be condensed into a smaller form..

//  Assign a class to all the image Links

```
.links
{
    width : 130px;
    height : 49px;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

<img src="Images/1Lust.png" class="links" id="button1">

//  Assign a class to all the images as a Whole
.images
{
    width : 880px;
    height : 600px;
    display: none;
}
<img src="Images/Deadly Sin 1.jpg" class="images">
```

**JavaScript**
// this block will cause the buttons to be opaque

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a img').animate({
        opacity: .5
    });
    // will change opacity to 1 on hover and back to .5 when not 
    $('a img').hover(function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 'fast');
    }, function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            opacity: .5
        }, 'fast');

    });

    $('#Image1').fadeIn(1500); 

    // Assign the click event to All the id's that start with button
    $('[id^="button"]').on('click', function() {
        //  fade Out All the images inside sins
        $('#sins img').fadeOut('slow');
        // Find the index of the element that was clicked
        var $index = $('#links').find(this).index();
        // Show the corresponding image
        $('#sins img:eq('+ ($index + 1) + ')').fadeIn(1500);
    });
});
```